# Change debug port for nodemon or mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-inspector, nodemon

I can use node-inspector to debug my nodemon app. But I want to also debug my tests. So I learnt that I need to start mocha in debug mode too (`mocha --debug`) problem is, this will try to debug on port 5858 by default too which in my case nodemon is using. So I will need to change the debug port of either, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Ok figured I can use `mocha --debug=8101` to change mocha's debug port.

Answer (score 2):

The same command line parameter works for `nodemon` and `node`. To bind on a different address, you can specify the IP like `--debug=127.0.0.1:5858` (which is the default since Node.js v7), or use a wildcard `--debug=[::]:5858` (which was the default in Node.js v6 and lower).